# In JAVA, do comments throw off the line numbering for a stack trace?

Tags: java, comments

Do single line comments (//) take up a line number in compiled code?  I mean, if I have this code:

```
int i = 0;
// next integer declaration...
int j = 1;
```

if in my IDE, these are lines 20, 21 and 22.  Will the declarations be on line 20 and 21 when decompiled?

I ask because stack traces often point to the wrong line and I feel these comments throw everything off.

While it doesn't appear that /* */  and  /** */ do.  Am I right?

Comment: Why not [try it out (`ideone.com`)](https://ideone.com/YbJSfG)?

Comment: Do you think that stack trace line numbers would be useful if they gave the wrong line number for any source code that contained comments (or empty lines, or multiple statements on a line)?

Comment: @khelwood aww you spoiled the surprise :(

Comment: @khelwood or have you?!

Comment: I don't have any problem even if lots of blanks lines and both types of comments.  StackTrace still give me the right line number for the exception.

Comment: *I ask because stack traces often point to the wrong line* I wouldn't say stack traces **often** point to the wrong line. If they do that, it **may** indicate code is swallowing exceptions that should not be swallowed. Can you give more context for your assertion?

Comment: This is easily tested with a few lines of code and causing an IndexOutOfBoundsException when indexing an array.